# How to verify if a string.split() returns null

Tags: java, split

I am reading data from a file:

```
Some Name;1|IN03PLF;IN02SDI;IN03MAP;IN02SDA;IN01ARC
Some Other Name;2|IN01ALG;IN01ANZ
Another Name;3|
Test Testson;4|IN03MAP;IN01ARC;IN01ALG
```

I use string.split() for every line I read from that file, like this:

```
String args[]         = line.split("\\|");                  
String candidatArgs[] = args[0].split(";");

if (args[1] != "" || args[1] != null) { 

    String inscrieriString[] = args[1].split(";");
```

**Thing is:** when I reach `Another Name;3|` after `.split("\\|")` the second part (`args[1]`) should be empty, either `null` or `""`  (I don't really know).

**However** I get an Array index out of bounds error on `if (args[1] != "" || args[1] != null)` (again, at: `Another Name;3|`)

Comment: From the sample data you posted its possible to get `String.split` arrays with length 1. You need to do bound checking for this in your code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The args will only have one element in it.

```
if (args.length > 1) {
    String inscrieriString[] = args[1].split(";");
}
```

Comment: This is crazy (correct ..  but still crazy).  If the array is empty, it will have a length of 1.  If if has one element, it will have a length of 2?  VB is not nice

Comment: I do not believe that's the most reliable way to check if the split operation was successful. If the delimiter is present only at the beginning or the end, of the string then the array will still have length of 1 but the split operation would be successful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the length of your `args` array.

[`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns an array of length 1 for your third line, so that `args[1]` is out of bounds.
You should also use [`String.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) instead of `!= ""`.

Most likely, you can even skip your additional checks - checking the array length should be sufficient:

```
if (args.length > 1) {
    String inscrieriString[] = args[1].split(";");
    ...
}
```

Comment: indeed, check if your args array size > 1. If not, do the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of `args` when splitting and only access the other index if the length allows it (if the `args.length > 1`).

In this case:

```
String line = "Another Name;3|"; //simplified for the example
line.split("\\|");
```

It will return this array:

```
{ "Another Name;3" }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String args[]         = line.split("\\|",2);                  
String candidatArgs[] = args[0].split(";");

if (args.length==2) 
    String inscrieriString[] = args[1].split(";");
```

Answer (score 1):

`args[1]` isn't empty or null. It is out of bounds in the array.

```
System.out.println("Another Name;3|".split("\\|").length);
```

You would need to check the length of the array before using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can test the length of args and it should return 1 or 2. If it's 1 you know that there's no args[1].